# How do I set Python 3.11.1 as default in Linux Mint?

Tags: python, linux

I'm running Linux Mint 21.1, and I'm trying to set the Python 3.11.1 interpreter as default. The problem is that I simply cannot get the command "python3" to point to my Python 3.11.1 installation.

3.11.1 is installed and fully functional in the same "/usr/lib/" directory as Python 2.7 and Python 3.10.6. I just want 3.11.1 to be the MAIN Python that is used systemwide.

I have:

- Added Python 2.7, 3.10.6, and 3.11.1 to a group called "python" with update-alternatives and have set 3.11.1 as the default,
- Changed the alias of the "python3" command to point to "/usr/lib/python3.11", only to find that it just echoes the directory and doesn't run the python 3.11 executable (or whatever it is called in linux),
- Added the location of the Python 3.11.1 directory to the PATH variable.

In this process, I somehow got the command "python3.11" to start an instance of the 3.11.1 interpreter, while "python3" does the same in 3.10.6. I have no idea how or why this is happening.

None of the things I have done have worked towards my desired end. I just want "python3" to run Python 3.11.1 instead of 3.10.6, and I want this to be reflected systemwide (i.e. in VSCode, terminal, when running a file, etc.). I can't imagine I'm the first person to have this issue, so my question is how do I ensure that 3.11.1 is the default Python version on my system?

Comment: In general you do not want to change your system/default python. This is part of your system and it can break the system if you alter it. If you want to use python 3.11 for specific projects (there is no reason to use 3.11 "system-wide" because your system is set up for the python that is already installed) - anyway, to use 3.11 for a specific project I would recommend using Miniconda to handle creating virtual environments and you can create environments with any python version you need or want. Another option is pyenv for Linux.

Comment: @topsail Thanks for the response! I guess using a virtual environment would work... But venv, my preferred virtual environment tool, gives me an error every time I try running it. Even if I use Miniconda or pyenv, I still end up using Python 3.10.6. In Windows upgrading python is as simple as installing the latest version, so I just thought that the process would be at least comparable on Linux, due to how widespread Python is. I've also never heard of a system being set up for a specific version of Python such that upgrading would be rendered impossible... But I'll do some more research.

Comment: I wouldn't say upgrading system python in linux is impossible ... just not recommendable. There is a huge difference between Windows and Linux distros in this regard - the Windows OS does not use python, where as Linux distros come packaged with python and uses python as part of a typical suite of applications, services, and utilities. Python versions will be managed by your packaging system and will be updated by the same - for you but also for your system. So again, in general, you should let the package system handle it. As for your problems with virtual environments, more detail is needed.

Answer (score 0):

conda will not yet allow (succeed) to create an environment with python 3.11.1 or 3.11 because there is no package available yet for this version. See issue [issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11170) or [PR](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/pull/31170)

on my mint21 machine, python3 is a symbolic link in `/usr/bin/` pointing to `/usr/bin/pyton3.10` (you can check this via `readlink -f python3` within the directory which is provided by `which python3`)

personally, **I wouldn't change it** - but I assume you could, if you update the link via `sudo ln -vfs python3 <path/to/python3.11.1/binary>` (verbose, force, symbolic - details see `man ln`)

If your prev. attempt *"just echoes the directory and doesn't run the python 3.11 executable"*, I assume that you're not pointing to the binary of python3.11.1 (you can validate this via `file <path/to/python3.11.1/you/used/for/the/change>`- the output should mention "executable")

I do not know if mint will have a problem if you do this change. Please consider that the shipped distribution is tested and you're about to change defaults.